# libxml2 not included when running iOS app in physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, libxml2

I'm using Fuzi ([GitHub](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi)) to parse an HTML page in my (Swift 3) iOS app. I use XCode 8.

It's all ok when I run my app in an emulator, but when I run it in a physical device I get many compilation-time errors from Fuzi, probably because libxml2 has not been included in the build.

I used CocoaPods to include Fuzi in my project, and it's really all ok when I use an emulator.

How can I solve this problem?